# Take different between two dates and set the difference in days in a another field value

Tags: angular, typescript, datetime, validation

I have two date fields. One is **Commencement Date** and the other one is **Expiration Date**.

**Requirement:**

> 1. When user selects commencement and expiration dates, I want to get the difference of those two dates (expirationDate - commecementDate)
>    **in days** and set that difference as the **value** in
>    **another textbox called Term**.
> 2. Should display **client side validation messages** necessary.

**Issues:**

> 1. When user select a expiration date first and secondly fill the commencement date, Term field not displaying any value.
> 2. Not displaying validation messages.

**Please find my stackblitz code** [here](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-yqyz4w?file=src/app/app.component.html).

Answer (score 0):

showing validation work fine;

try this:

```
import { Component, VERSION } from '@angular/core';
import { FormControl, FormGroup, Validators } from '@angular/forms';

@Component({
  selector: 'my-app',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./app.component.css'],
})
export class AppComponent {
  name = 'Angular ' + VERSION.major;
  public commencementDate: any;
  public expirationDate: any;
  public noOfdays: any;

  compsForm: FormGroup = new FormGroup({
    leaseCommencement: new FormControl('', Validators.required),
    leaseExpiration: new FormControl('', Validators.required),
    term: new FormControl(''),
  });

  commencementEvent(event: any) {
    let date = event.target.value;
    this.commencementDate = new Date(date);
    this.check();
  }

  expirationEvent(event: any) {
    let date = event.target.value;
    this.expirationDate = new Date(date);
    this.check();
  }

  check() {
    if (this.commencementDate && this.expirationDate) {
      var time =
        this.expirationDate.getTime() - this.commencementDate.getTime();
      var days = time / (1000 * 3600 * 24); //Diference in Days

      if (days && days >= 0) {
        this.noOfdays = days;
      } else {
        this.noOfdays = null;
      }
    }
  }

  saveComp(value: any): void {
    console.log(value);
  }

  cancel(): void {
    console.log('cancel');
  }
}
```

try handling validation by reactiveForm its Own (abstractControl)

and you can also use observale , it has great simple operators that make code simple